# How does a Hadoop or Spark connector for distributed data stores function?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, distributed-computing

Spark has connectors for a variety of databases and data stores.

However, what would be required to create a connector for your own custom distributed database.
From what I understand, Spark uses Hadoop connectors to fetch data from a distributed data store. I wasn't able to find a good resource to understand how a Hadoop connector works and how one can be made.

I'm looking to understand the semantics of a Hadoop connector so as to be able to create one for my custom database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a Record Reader using Java with the Hadoop API

Then Spark will be able to use it

My sugestion is start by reading Tom White's book

Comment: This seems to be the book http://www.amazon.com/Hadoop-Definitive-Guide-Tom-White/dp/1449311520